# Perform action when soft keyboard is closing

Tags: java, android, onclick, keyboard

I want to perform a method when the soft keyboard is closing. I tried overriding the onBackPressed() method but it didn't work because the back-button changes when the soft keyboard is open (below is a screenshot of the button).

[Hide-Soft-Keyboard-Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjH9w.png)

I tried using the OnKeyListener but it turned out that it doesn't work with the soft keyboard. And I also don't know the keyCode of this "hide-soft-keyboard-button" either...

I would appreciate any help since couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: What type of action are you trying to run. Another alternative would be to have focus change listener on the EditText fields and perform action based on that?

Comment: I have an EditText which get's enabled when a specific add-button is pressed, the focus is then set on the EditText and the keyboard shows up. I want it to "disappear" when the user closes the keyboard.

How would I use the focus change listener? I'm still a noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could  use a layout listener to see if the root layout of your activity is resized by the keyboard but detecting whether the softkeyboard is shown or has disappeared is only possible with some workarounds and hacks, hence i would not recommend it.

It would be more appropriate to set a Focus change listener on your edittext :

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
 public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        //got focus
    } else {
        //lost focus
    }
  }
});
```